# "Tensor complement" of representations of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional simple $G$-representation (over $\mathbb{C}$) for a finite group $G$. Let $R$ be the regular representation of $G$.

Is there a $G$-representation $W$ such that $V \otimes W \cong R$?

Comment: Haven't checked the details, but I think the standard representation of $S_3$ should provide a counterexample

Comment: @leibnewtz: it doesn't. I checked several examples fully expecting to quickly find a counterexample and haven't so far.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Dang. Well it definitely feels false

Comment: One observation so far: this would be false if $V$ 1) had degree greater than $1$ and 2) its character was nowhere $0$. But apparently no such $V$ exists: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_character_of_degree_greater_than_one_takes_value_zero_on_some_conjugacy_class

Comment: I wonder if such an isomorphism would necessarily have to commute with the $G \times G$ action

Comment: Such an isomorphism would give a proof of the fact that $\dim V$ divides $|G|$ for any irrep $V$. The proofs of this fact that I know of are kinda ugly and use some results about algebraic integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my rather amateurish (so it would be good if somebody checked independently) GAP calculations, this is false for $G=SL(2,5)$ and $V$ either of the $4$-dimensional irreducible representations.

In fact, more is false. There are no representations $W_1$ and $W_2$ so that
$$R\oplus (V\otimes W_1)\cong V\otimes W_2,$$
so if $V$ has character $\psi$ and the irreducible characters are $\chi_1,\dots,\chi_n$, then the regular character is not an integer linear combination of $\psi\otimes\chi_1,\dots,\psi\otimes\chi_n$.

The $SL(2,5)$ example is probably small enough to verify by hand, but it can be done in GAP using only built-in functions, with no non-trivial programming. GAP has functions to do things like constructing tensor products of characters and calculating scalar products of characters, so it is easy to construct the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ such that
$$\psi\otimes\chi_i=a_{i1}\chi_1+\dots+a_{in}\chi_n$$
for each irreducible character $\chi_i$. Then it remains to check, for $b=(b_i)$ the row vector such that the regular character is
$$b_1\chi_1+\dots+b_n\chi_n,$$
whether $b$ is an integer linear combination of the rows of $A$, or in other words whether the matrix equation $b=xA$ has a solution $x$ that is an integer vector. Luckily GAP has a function $\text{SolutionIntMat}$ that does this.

I don’t know whether there’s an easy way using only built-in functions to check whether there is a solution of $b=xA$ that is a *non-negative* integer vector, so this method might be missing some smaller examples that answer the original question.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have no experience with GAP (or any similar software); could you describe roughly how you obtained this answer from it (e.g., by copy/pasting some lines of code into your answer)?

Comment: @rj7k8 I think “code” is overstating what it is. I did little more than use built-in GAP commands in a rather clunky way. But I’ve added a description of what’s involved.

Comment: By the way, I just tested all groups of size up to 120, and there are some smaller counterexamples (to the weaker statement that I tested): three groups of order 72. There are also four of order 120 other than $SL(2,5)$.